# How ";" sign separate transaction in XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Suppose we want to call `function1 ()` and `function2()`.

But `function1()` and `function2()` must be occurring in a serialized way i.e. if `function1()` executes then only `function2()` would execute.

I don't want to use `eval()` instead I want to separate transaction with the help of `;` .

Comment: Have you read http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_68542 yet?

Comment: Satyam, If the two functions are independent then the order in which they are executed isn't important. If they are dependent, the functions either have side effects or the result of the first function is passed as a parameter to the second. Please, edit the question and specify which of the three cases you have.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it for instance like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace "my" at "/my-lib.xqy";

my:function1()

;
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace "my" at "/my-lib.xqy";

my:function2()
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(function1(),function2())
```